# Conda - Can't import install quandl

Tags: python, importerror, conda, quandl

As the title indicates I can't seem to import the installed library package `quandl`. This is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-8-ab7fa5ad38a5>", line 1, in <module>
    import quandl
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quandl'
```

To note, I've researched this issue fairly thoroughly and have tried the following solutions:

1) Uninstalled extra python environments. I only have one Python running now [in conda]

2) Install via `conda install quandl`

3) Use the following solution:

```
source activate my-env
conda remove conda-build
conda remove conda-env
conda update anaconda
```

One thing I did notice is that `quandl` appears when I input `conda list` in terminal but isn't listed under Settings-->Project Interpreter, suggesting that the packaging may have been installed at another directory by mistake. Is there a simple solution to this, other than manually installing into the conda directory where the other packages are located.

Comment: Looks like you IDE is using my-env, not conda-env

Comment: When you run: conda list it would show the path to that env. 
you would need to explicitly point your IDE interpreter to it.